# How to display all uploaded images those r stored into hard disk by a user into his home page

Tags: php

I am preparing a application in which i am asking user to upload his images and now i want that this images displayed when user log in and click on my photos link(in thumbnails).I think you got the idea.All is same like orkut..

Now what I can do in this is...

I can upload the file and can store it into hardisk into any folder(/htodocs/uploadedfiles) but i dont know how to display this hard disk stored image into my page like orkut does..
and then i want to provide a delete button at the bottom of each image so that if user want to delete uploaded image it get deleted from hard-sisk as well as from database..Give me idea about this also.BUt tell me how i can display an image on page which i have stored into hard disk..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After uploading the image file, store the image into require path using move_upload_file function. then store the image file path in database for that user.

Then, whenever you want that image, you use that image path for accessing the image in php.

For delete you can unlink function, Whenever delete link is get clicked, you call the unlink function with that image file path, it will get removed from your file system.

Comment: yaa i was thinking the same i tried like this..I am able to move this file into desired location no problem there then i am displaying image using img tag but this is not working...

 $addr=$row['File']['Name']; and then to display this image i am trying  <img src="<?php echo $addr ?>"> but this is not working